# multiple values for same filter

Tags: seo, plugin, multiple-select-layered

Does Magento support multiple values for same filter natively?

I'm aware there are plugins that enable store customer to apply multiple values of the same filter criteria; I used some of those in the past, now I disabled them all and still URL like `filter_name=949_822_821_948_944_820_939` works.

Thanks